# WooCommerce SEPA eMandat Payment

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, woocommerce

I guess Single European Payment Area (SEPA) is becoming mandatory pretty soon. In Germany early next year. Are there any payment modules for woocommerce out there yet?

Answer (score 1):

There is a ready to use plugin : http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-sepa-payment-gateway/7963419